# Show 404 if slug is not present from the CMS Strapi

Tags: next.js, content-management-system, strapi

[image: Network status code is 200]I am working with Strapi CMS and Next.js on showing page from strapi cms need to change the status code to 404 on the browser network window

Whenever a person enters unknown page where data is not found on CMS. Need to redirect it to error page and gave 404 error response in the browser network console.

Here is app pages structure

`

```
      app > 
        lamguage > 
            page.tsx
            Layout.tsx
            loading.tsx
            RootLayout.tsx
                     slug -->
                             page.tsx
                             layout.tsx
                             404.tsx`
```

It is gaving me 404 page on certain condition perfectly but not 404 response status code in the network tab.

I have tried **notfound **from documentation
custom 404 pages

What am trying to do is whenver it goes to some other slug from which CMS there is no data showing me the 404 page but not response

For your refereal starter code

```
https://github.com/strapi/nextjs-corporate-starter
```